# how to stop countdown timer from looping when frames loop Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, countdowntimer

I am currently creating a game that requires a countdown timer which starts at 60seconds, however the timer consistently loops itself after 4 seconds.

Below is the code that I've used in Adobe Animate and it constantly loops when frames complete

```
import flash.utils.Timer;

var count:Number = 60;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,count);
myTimer.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.start();

function countdown(event:TimerEvent) : void
{
Timer_txt.text = String ((count)-myTimer.currentCount + " seconds");
}
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question?  What output do you see in your `Timer_txt` element, and what do you *expect* to see?  Also, where do you have this code defined -- is it just on a timeline, inside an ENTER_FRAME listener, or inside a class somewhere?

Comment: When i run the animation, Timer_txt displays "60 seconds". However once it hits "56 seconds" the countdown timer loops back to 60 seconds again. I created a game that requires countdown timer that limit the playtime to 60 seconds and I loop frames by coding this.gotoAndPlay(); but once I add the countdown timer it loops as well. My question is how to make the timer continue to countdown while the frames loop? It would be great if anyone could help me thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to use a Document class?  When you put code on the timeline, each keyframe gets run separately.  Your timer will get recreated if it's on the timeline because of that (I'm guessing your frames add up to 4 seconds?).  If you put it in a Document class, though, the frame looping around won't affect the timer anymore.

Comment: I don't really know how to use Document class. And yes my frames add up to 4 seconds. Thanks for your help I'll try to figure out how to use Document class.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the constructor method incorrectly. After looking at the API doc[(here)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html), I found that

```
myTimer: Timer = new Timer(1000, 60);
```

would create a timer that the timer will run every 1000 milliseconds and it will repeat 60 times (and then stop working). That's clearly not what you are after. If I understand correctly, you want a timer to count to 60 and then reset back to 0. So to do that:

```
myTimer: Timer = new Timer(1000);
```

is all you need for the constructor. But now you need to add something that resets the timer to 0 after the timer ticks 60 times. Use a check against your `count` variable. Like this:

```
if (myTimer.currentCount >= count)
{ 
    myTimer.reset();
}
```

I've never done this, but it looks like it should work. Then you can have your timer text field update each timer event similarly to how you have it set up.